# ArrayList or several for loops?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, arraylist

I know this might be simple, I have a situation where I need to decide between using four for-loops to (two to count and remove null elements, two to add elements) merge two String arrays or use two for-loops with an ArrayList and convert the ArrayList to array using ArrayList.toArray().

Performance wise are there any differences between these two approaches?

EDIT

I had to drop the ArrayList with generics approach because of compatibility issues. But here is the earlier code.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String element : array1)
    {
      if (element != null)
      {
        newList.add(element);
      }
    }

    for (String element : array2)
    {
      if (element != null)
      {
        newList.add(element);
      }
    }

    return newList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

I wrote a new code with one loop, but I think I might be mentally killing the next one reading this code.

```
String[] newArr = new String[array1.length + array2.length];
int n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
{
  if (i < array1.length && array1[i] != null)
  {
    newArr[n] = array1[i];
    n++;
  }

  if (i >= array1.length)
  {
    int a = 0;
    if (array1.length < array2.length)
    {
      a = (i - array1.length) + (array2.length - array1.length);
    }
    else
    {
      a = i - array1.length;
    }

    if (array2[a] != null)
    {
      newArr[n] = array2[a];
      n++;
    }
  }
}

return newArr;
```

And finally got to know that null element check won't be needed so went ahead with this simple code.

```
String[] newArr = new String[array1.length + array2.length];

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, newArr, 0, array1.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, newArr, array1.length, array2.length);

    return newArr;
```

I guess from the discussion below the second method is the better performing one.

Comment: Can you paste your code ?

Comment: You might want to consider using LinkedList instead, unless you know the size of the array in beforehand.

Comment: It probably depends. It usually does. So benchmark it, with exactly *your* realistic scenario, and compare. Btw, LinkedList is usually disappointingly slow.

Comment: @harold That depends on what you're using the LinkedList for. If you want random access to your List then ArrayList is a far better option. But if you don't know how long the list should be in beforehand, an ArrayList will resize itself multiple times unless you give it enough starting capacity.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yes, but that isn't really so bad. Adding items to an ArrayList is still O(1) amortized time, and more importantly, it's fast in practice. I've almost never found a LinkedList to be faster in practice, especially not in a case like this where you only append onto the end and then iterate over the items. So always try it to make sure it's really an improvement.

Comment: Without saying what your merge means, this question makes no sense. I guess you really want to remove nulls and concatenate the rest. But then neither of your solution is optimal (w.r.t. to either performance or clarity).

Comment: @Chamilla: So, like, you are unwilling to benchmark your own code, and you think we'll do it for you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crowdsourcing benchmarking efforts. The question is too localized to be of much use to anyone.

Comment: I'd guess the second loop is slower. Anyway, it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg LinkedList is *never* an option when we are talking about performance.

Comment: @leventov I'll start make benchmarking tests from now on whenever I'm unsure about which one to use.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg: Many people (including me) did, and the outcome is that LinkedList is nearly always an error. The notable exception are `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` and alike. Consider using LinkedList only if there are many iterator-based deletions and hardly any traversals.

Comment: @KubaOber: I was on a tight schedule, and didn't want to spend time on benchmarking a small method of a much larger flow. Just wanted to know if there was a practiced way of doing things in this kind of a situation. and no, I didn't want to "crowd-source" benchmarking efforts (whatever that is).

Comment: @Chamila: If you're on a tight schedule, premature optimizations make little sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1 for loop has O(n) time complexity, 4 for loops and 2 for loops would have the same time complexity

```
4*O(n) = O(n)
2*O(n) = O(n)
```

But using arrays instead of ArrayLists would take less memory. So go with the first alternative.

Comment: `would take the same time` this is a misnomer. They absolutely do not take the same time. They just belong to the same time complexity class. Two very different things.

Comment: They do take different times, but when we talk about large data we do tend to ignore such differences. right ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi In theoretical computer science an algorithm taking "twice as long as another" is more-or-less irrelevant. We're only particularly concerned with at which rate does the algorithm grow as n increases. The being said, in real world applications, a factor of 2 is enormous, especially if the shorter one is already human-noticeable amounts of time.

Comment: when we talk about larger data, we talk about a bigger difference.

Comment: So it makes no difference whether something takes a day, or two days?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid looping as much as you can because every time u loop with `n` elements the time and space complexity increases by `n`.

Please paste your code.

Comment: `for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){for(int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++){}}}` has O(1) space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

as with second option 2 iterations over collection will be saved, this will definitely improve performance if count of objects in list is high.